# Генерация изображения средствами java

Tags: java, изображения, jpeg

Как реализовать механизм генерации изображения с текстом средствами голой java?

Comment: Можно, ИМХО, Вы бы все же глянули на правила форума, где рассказывают как задать вопрос, чтобы получить на него ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Да, средствами голой java можно реализовать механизм генерации изображения, в том числе из строки.

Comment: @Kromster можно строку преобразовать в байтовый массив, но уровень абсурдности происходящего при этом возрастёт. А он и так уже не мал :)

Comment: Я больше намекаю на то, что вопрос безумно широк, и можно парсить строку 1001 способом, от сырого преобразования, base64 декодирования, и до парсинга команд отрисовки геом.фигур или использования нейросети. Так что дополнение про "Только не из строки, а из массива байт" лишнее.

Comment: @Kromster исправил XD